# What's the best way to format quotes within quotes?

Tags: discussion, formatting

If the source you are quoting itself contains a quote, how would do you format it?  You can double up the greater-than signs (`>>`), but I don't find this sort of double quote clear or pleasing on the eye; for example, if I quote the Wikipedia entry on Oscar Wilde:

> Isola died aged eight of meningitis. Wilde's poem "Requiescat" is dedicated to her memory:
>
> > Tread lightly, she is near
> >     Under the snow
> >     Speak gently, she can hear
> >     the daisies grow

Comment: a simple `> >` double quote seems plenty clear to me, and not displeasing to my eye, at least... I would avoid 3 levels of quoting though just on principle.

Comment: Nested quotes *used* to look perfectly fine, while we still had the quote-mark images on them. Sniff.